# Adjusting targetNamespace in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to create a translation document to rollback our newer message bodies. I was able to roll back the namespace with no issues but having issues rolling back the targetNamespace.

In the java code the targetNamespace is set to new_namespace:1.1.0
The incoming xml message looks like this.

```
<env xmlns="original_cap_namespace" targetNamespace="new_namespace:1.1.0"</env>
```

I want the outbound message to look like this(replace the cap namespace with the new_namespace and remove the versioning on the taretNamespace)

```
<env xmlns="new_namespace" targetNamespace="new_namespace" </env>
```

Here is what I tried. This works to replace the original_cap_namespace with the new_namespace. I cant seem to figure out how to strip the versioning from the targetNamespace or set the targetNamespace to the new_namespace just like the xmlns. I want the xmlns and the targetNamespace both to be set to the new_namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="new_namespace"
xmlns:cap="original_cap_namespace"
exclude-result-prefixes="cap">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" standalone="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='env']">
    <env xmlns="new_namespace">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </env>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cant seem to figure out how to strip the versioning from the
>   targetNamespace or set the targetNamespace to the new_namespace just
>   like the xmlns.

`targetNamespace` is an attribute, not a namespace declaration, so you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="@targetNamespace">
    <xsl:attribute name="targetNamespace">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(../@targetNamespace, ':')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

to strip the version, or:

```
<xsl:template match="@targetNamespace">
    <xsl:attribute name="targetNamespace">new_namespace</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

to set the contents to a known string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I swore it was part of the namespace declaration. Make it look too easy hahah.

Comment: Complete answer about the `targetNamespace` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will cover the way you are dealing with namespaces.

- You use `/*[local-name()='env']` as pattern but what you really want is to change the namespace for an element under another specific namespace. Something more like `cap:env`.
- Another problem cames from the rule for every attribute `@*` with a template content that outputs an attribute with only the local part of the QName. That way you will lose any attribute under a namespace (even `@xml:id`)
- Finally, the same problem for attributes happens with the rule for every element `*`: it keept only the local part of the QName, which results in an element under the default namespace in effect (the `new_namespace` of your literal result element `env`). That way you also will lose any element from a different vocabulary than `original_cap_namespace`.